# убрать подсвечивание ссылки после активации

Tags: html, css

```
<p><a href="1.html">Ссылка 1</a></p>
<p><a href="2.html">Ссылка 2</a></p>
<p><a href="3.html">Ссылка 3</a></p>
```

например, такие кнопки. как сделать так, чтобы после активации ссылки, при отводе от неё курсора она не подсвечивалась точечным пунктиром(см.картинку)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это выделен текущий объект, а если попробовать Яваскриптом или Jquery выделить какой то другой объект?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это свойство активных элементов называется `outline`. По-умолчанию браузеры таким образом выделяют элемент, с которым взаимодействует пользователь. Причем, это не только ссылки, но и кнопки, поля ввода и т.д.

Подробнее http://htmlbook.ru/css/outline-style

Убрать легко. Добавьте в CSS ссылке (или даже всем `a`) свойство

```
outline: none !important;
```